# How to pass JavaScript variable to Symfony route using Twig path function

Tags: javascript, symfony, url, twig

I have a small problem with a Javascript variable in a Twig template,
what I want is to pass a variable as a parameter (in a url) to a function. All I have found on StackOverflow is how to pass a string **'blablabla'** to the URL like:

```
url/{param}, {'param' : 'blablabla'}
```

but I want something like :

```
$var =...;
url/{param}, {'param': $var}
```

this photo should make it clear to you , thanks for reading

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ3Wn.png)

Comment: Can't be done that way. Twig is rendered on the server. You need to use ajax or [fosrouting](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks Man , any useful links for ajax or fosrouting  to solve this issue ??

Comment: Click on the blue word fosrouting. Is a "How To"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use the FOS JsRouting bundle. It is totally suited to what you want to do.

Here is the official documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Example in Twig :

```
Routing.generate('your_route_with_params', { param: varJavascript });
```

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you , I will  read the documentation carefully and I hope I can get what I want